# How does cloudflare proxy work via dns records

Tags: proxy, reverse-proxy, cloudflare, nginx-reverse-proxy, openresty

I'm working on a project that provides protection for websites via reverse proxy nginx. My issue is that I want to be able to do something similar as cloudflare which sets up the proxy through the dns set up what are some ways to achieve this?

currently using nginx and having the proxy conf set up like this

proxy_pass https://1.1.1.1/;
proxy_set_header Host domain.com;